# htaccess change domain name with exception for prefix "www."

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to achieve the following with htaccess for my domain 'example.com':

1. Always add 'https://' before the domain name or change 'http://' into 'https://';
2. Add prefix 'www.' before the domain name (after 'https://') if no prefix is used, and do not change other prefixes (like 'mobile.').

So 'example.com' or 'http://example.com' will change into: 'https://www.example.com' and
'mobile.example.com' or 'http://mobile.example.com' will change into 'https://mobile.example.com'.

Answer (score 0):

your `.htaccess` file should be :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Start with www
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

    # force http to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]


    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple **.htaccess** file to change **http -> https** and adding **www** if not set

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: This is nice compact; but it does not change `mobile.example.com` into `https://mobile.example.com`.  

What I want as results is:  

`example.com` into `https://www.example.com`;  `http://example.com` into `https://www.example.com`; `http://www.example.com` into `https://www.example.com`; `mobile.example.com` into `https://mobile.example.com`; `http://mobile.example.com` into `https://mobile.example.com`

Comment: if you have 1 directory for root (www) and another for subdomain, you can add 2 .htaccess files with redirection. This is for subdomain: 
`RewriteRule (.*) https://mobile.example.com/$1 [R=301,QSA]`

Comment: This is not clear for me Buffy. If I should add 2 .htaccess files, I would have 3 in total. For what, where and with what content?